# Spivak Calculus on Manifolds, Theorem 5-2

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In the proof Theorem 5-2 of Spivak *Calculus on Mannifolds* how is
\begin{align*}
V_2\cap M=\{f(a):(a,0)\in V_1\}?
\end{align*}
(That $\{f(a):(a,0)\in V_1\}=\{g(a,0):(a,0)\in V_1\}$ is clear.)

**Edit**:  Due to a comment, Theorem 5-2 proves the equivalence of the following two definitions of a $k$-dimensional regular submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Definition 1**.  A subset $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a **$k$-dimensional submanifold** if for every point $x\in M$ the following condition is satisfied:

(M)  There is an open set $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ containing $x$, an open set $V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, and a diffeomorphism $h:U\rightarrow V$ such that
\begin{align*}
h(U\cap M)&=V\cap(\mathbb{R}^k\times\{0\})\\
&=\{y\in V:y^{k+1}=\dots=y^n\}.
\end{align*}

**Definition 2**.  A subset $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a **$k$-dimensional submanifold** if for every point $x\in M$ the following "coordinate condition" is satisfied:

(C) There is an open set $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ containing $x$, an open set $W\subset\mathbb{R}^k$, and an injective differentiable function $f:W\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying:

1. $f(W)=M\cap U$.
2. $f'(y)$ has maximum rank $k$ for each $y\in W$.
3. $f^{-1}:f(W)\rightarrow W$ is continuous.

The part of the proof mentioned above is proving Definition 2 $\Rightarrow$ Definition 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** As RRTT points out in the comments, the following proof is ***incorrect*** as written.

Here is a justification:

$$\begin{align}
V_2 \cap M = V_2' \cap U \cap M & = (V_2' \cap U) \cap (U \cap M) \\
& = (V_2' \cap U) \cap f(W) \\
& = (V_2' \cap U) \cap \{f(a) \colon (a,0) \in V_1'\} \\
& = \{g(a,0) \in U \cap V_2' \colon (a,0) \in V_1'\} \\
& = \{g(a,0) \colon (a,0) \in V_1' \cap g^{-1}(U \cap V_2')\} \\
& = \{g(a,0) \colon (a,0) \in V_1' \cap V_1\} \\
& = \{f(a) \colon (a,0) \in V_1\}. \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: why is $U \cap M = f(W)$?  The $U$ from the statement of the theorem might not be this $U$ that came from continuity of the inverse.

Comment: @RRTT: Thank you for catching that; you're absolutely right.  Looking back on this, there are several things I don't quite like about what I have here.  Hm...

Comment: Maybe this works?: Let $U_0$ be the open set such that $f(W) = U_0 \cap M$ and instead define $V_2$ as $V_2 = V_2^{\prime} \cap U \cap U_0$